# Well supported higher level abstraction over Java's StAX XML streamer?

Tags: java, xml, java-stream, stax

I've looked around for an abstraction over the StAX API for streaming items from an XML file and have been unable to find any. Even for the most basic level of parsing (i.e, into a simple POJO or just to a Map). I've written my own that builds maps based on a tag that should be searched for but it's somewhat ugly and I feel like a better library must exist.

It ought to be a fairly common procedure to have to read large XML files, search for a specific tag by name and receive either a Stream or Iterator over objects representing these tags. At this point the StAX API is too low level for these needs as we have no reason to deal in terms of individual XML events.

Comment: The StAX API is low level by design. There are plenty of higher level APIs. If you want a high level API, why are you using StAX?

Comment: I recomend using https://vtd-xml.sourceforge.io this is the world fastest xml processor.

Comment: Building a tool atop another tool is not abstraction. An abstraction implies independence over details. If you want that, you have to name these details. At the moment, you just want a tool with a very detailed behavior.